# Library with multiple template definitions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, templates, static-libraries

I am learning on how create libraries using Visual Studio 2010. So to test the multiple symbols, I just wrote -

**add.cpp**

```
template <typename T>
T fooBar(T a1, T a2)
{
  return (a1+a2);
}
```

**subtract.cpp**

```
template <typename T>
T fooBar(T a1, T a2)
{
  return (a1-a2);
}
```

As far as I understand, templates is a compile time concept. Just to test how the tool behave between functions / function templates, I wrote the above. It successfully created `.lib` with out any warnings even at the highest level set for function templates. How ever, in case of normal functions it issued warnings.

> add.obj : warning LNK4006: "int __cdecl fooBar(int,int)" (?fooBar@@YAHHH@Z) already defined in subtract.obj; second definition ignored
>
> add.obj : warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible

Why is the tool behaving differently for functions vs function templates ?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `.lib` you get out?

Comment: From where are you referencing these functions? It's worrisome to me that you have these defined in `.cpp` files and not in `.h` or `.hxx` files.  Probably created the `.lib` without any warnings/errors because you weren't actually compiling them at all.

Comment: Did you try to instantiate the template function, say, by writing something like: int a; int b; int c = fooBar(a,b); ?  Otherwise the compiler will never instantiate the template and never have to pick between the two.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Yes. There are two lines specific to each source file with name mangling done. I amn't sure how far to check to be more specific.

Comment: @ChrisA What do you mean by not compiling at all ? They are `.cpp` files, and I see them being compiled on Visual Studio output window.

Comment: @Mahesh, I'll post an answer below based on what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are templated functions, the functions themselves won't get compiled until you actually instantiate the template function.

For instance, I just put the following code in one of my `.cpp` files without using it and the compilation of the `.cpp` file went through fine (despite the glaring syntax error):

```
template <typename J>
int foobar(J junk)
{
#pragma message("Compiling foobar")
     ppp = 35;

     return 0;
}
```

It's not until I try to compile it (that is create a compiler instance of it) with:

```
int main(void)
{
     double x;
     int y = foobar(x);
     return 0;
}
```

do I get a compilation error.

```
: error C2065: 'ppp' : undeclared identifier
```

Try this on your own and it might help you explain what you're seeing (at least the lack of error in the first case you mentioned.)

Comment: Can I take the point that there would be no warnings at all for a template if there is no template instantiation for it?

Comment: It's not compiled at all so there's no duplicate symbol etc. You'll get no warnings or errors or anything. If you put a `#pragma message("Compiling foobar")` inside the `foobar` function you'll see precisely when it's compiled.

Comment: I would like to add that function templates are allowed to have definitions in multiple translation units. However if the definitions are not identical then it's undefined behavior, which is the case here.